# "Can't alloc filename" when executing mdb-export on a mounted file

Tags: 12.04, mount, samba, cifs

I've mounted a Windows directory with CIFS :

```
sudo mount -t cifs //SERVER/Bases/some/path ~/mnt/data -o user=windomain/login%password
```

This works :

```
cp mnt/data/blabla/file.mdb .
/usr/bin/mdb-export file.mdb tablename
```

But this doesn't :

```
/usr/bin/mdb-export mnt/data/blabla/file.mdb tablename
```

It fails with output

```
Can't alloc filename
```

Why ? How can I execute `mdb-export` on a mounted file without having to copy it locally first ?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the output of `mount` please?

Comment: There's no output from the mount command. And I can list or copy the mounted files.

Comment: You sure you can't get this [output](http://pastebin.com/KpiuJ7Kd)? What's the output of `ls mnt/data/blabla/file.mdb`? BTW, did you notice that in the one that works you have `.MDB` (uppercase) and in the one that doesn't you have `.mdb` (lowercase)?

Comment: We really need the output from the command when it doesn't work. Not from the mount command, but from the mdb-export command.

Comment: @Braiam I thougth you were speaking of the mount I had made. Sorry. As for the MDB vs mdb, it's just an error in the question (obviously the paths are changed).

Comment: @FlorianMargaine The output of the mdb-export command was in the title. There was nothing more. I edited the question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to change the mount command to add the `noserverino,nounix` options :

```
sudo mount -t cifs //SERVER/Bases/some/path ~/mnt/data -o user=windomain/login%password,noserverino,nounix
```

---

Florian pointed me to the right direction, that is the `mdb_find_file` function in the source code of the MDB tools :

```
static gchar *mdb_find_file(char *file_name)
{
    struct stat status;
    gchar *mdbpath, **dir, *tmpfname;
    unsigned int i = 0;

    /* try the provided file name first */
    if (!stat(file_name, &status)) {
        return g_strdup(file_name);
    }

    /* Now pull apart $MDBPATH and try those */
    mdbpath = (gchar *) getenv("MDBPATH");
    /* no path, can't find file */
    if (!mdbpath || !strlen(mdbpath)) return NULL;

    dir = g_strsplit(mdbpath, ":", 0); 
    while (dir[i]) {
        if (!strlen(dir[i])) continue;
        tmpfname = g_strconcat(dir[i++], "/", file_name, NULL);
        if (!stat(tmpfname, &status)) {
            g_strfreev(dir);
            return tmpfname;
        }
        g_free(tmpfname);
    }
    g_strfreev(dir);
    return NULL;
}
```

As I don't have any `MDBPATH` env var, it's obvious that there is an error in the `stat` call. I googled in that direction and got this :

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/problem-with-stat-on-cifs-852983/

As I didn't try to recompile the MDB tools to get the error code, I'm not sure it's the same problem but adding the options that this thread suggested solved my problem, there's no more error when calling `mdb-export`.

Comment: Nice! Glad you could solve this.

Comment: TBH it's hardly satisfying. I don't really have enough time to experiment right now but there are many questions remaining. I don't even know what's the error code returned by `stat`...

Comment: You can ask another question then @dystroy also, you may like to [report a bug in the package](http://askubuntu.com/q/5121/169736)

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment.

This is where the error comes from:

```
mdb->f->filename = (char *) mdb_find_file(filename);
if (!mdb->f->filename) {.
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't alloc filename\n");
```

So let's see what `mdb_find_file` does...

Seeing the beginning of the function, this is probably what fails:

```
while (dir[i]) {
    if (!strlen(dir[i])) continue;
    tmpfname = g_strconcat(dir[i++], "/", file_name, NULL);
    if (!stat(tmpfname, &status)) {
        g_strfreev(dir);
        return tmpfname;
    }
    g_free(tmpfname);
}
g_strfreev(dir);
return NULL;
```

The function returns `NULL`, hence the fail later.

It looks like it's telling us that it can't find the filename.

Did you try using the full path? Did you try using the UNC path? Did you try using the `smb://` path?

Comment: So... is a bug, or more like a quark in the source code... this are things that I don't like :/

Comment: I've looked at the code. As I don't have any MDBPATH env variable (I give the full path), the problem seems to be with `stat(file_name, &status)` which returns non 0. Is that normal for a CIFS mounted file ?